# 401002 CA certificate not found - SDK - Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client

Tags: azure-iot-hub

```
OS - Windows 10
.net Environment - .net core 2.1
SDK - Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client - 1.21.0
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client - 1.4.0
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Transport.Amqp - 1.1.9
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Transport.Http - 1.1.6
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Transport.Mqtt - 1.1.8
```

**Description of the issue**

I'm trying to connect a simulated device (.net core console app) to IOT hub via azure Device Provisioning Service. This is based on x.509 cetificates (root+ intermediate certificate).

I created the enrolment group ok, then uploaded the root certificate and completed verification.

After that generated the device certificate from root certificate and tried to connect to IOT hub using sample code from below link:

```
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/provisioning/Samples/device/X509Sample
```

After having all setup when I tried to connect to IOT bub I'm getting below error, tried all protocol - Amqp,Http,Mqtt...

```
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.ProvisioningTransportException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message={"errorCode":401002,"trackingId":"408d5ad7-aa7c-45a1-b19a-e4af41ccf54b","message":"CA certificate not found.","timestampUtc":"2019-08-23T09:17:53.762099Z"}
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Below is the input to device client along with certificate:

```
    private static string s_idScope = "0ne00074417";
    private const string GlobalDeviceEndpoint = "global.azure-devices-provisioning.net";
    private static string s_certificateFileName = "simulateddevicecert.pfx";
```

Is there anything missing in the setup that is causing this error? Also is there any REST API exposed by azure DPS to register device? (instead of using Azure Devices/Client SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/provisioning/Samples/device/X509Sample#using-your-certificates), 
please include the intermediate certificate as well in the certificate chain presented by the device.

The REST API docs for registering a device to DPS can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/runtimeregistration/registerdevice).

Answer (score 0):

In my case error 401002 was caused by mismatched `deviceId` and `CN` field in certificate which device used to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the wrong connection string.
I used the `device connection string` instead of the `service connection string` when trying to call a direct invoke method.

I'm posting this here, because this is among the first search results for the 401002 error, and there's no info on this check on the Azure doc websites.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to this thread in case someone encounters the same issue but cannot resolve it with the provided answer.

In my case, I was trying to register a "device" programmatically to an enrollment group in the DPS using X509 certificate. This is done in our integration tests. Therefore, we are using an actual sub-CA certificate (not self-signed root).
I had the same exception running the integration test on my Windows corporate laptop, **but it was due to the fact that I did not have imported the certificate into the certificate store.**

To add the signing certificates to the store you can do it by hand:
[PrintScreenCertificateManagementWindows]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D1Ro.png

And indeed, your PFX file should contain the full chain:

- Root public cert
- Intermediate public cert
- Device public cert
- Private key of Device Cert

I hope this help someone else.

Cheers,

Jamal